# Implementation of rewind(file offset) in c

Tags: c, file-io

Can anyone explain the implementation/algo that was used in rewind function? or is it possible to implement rewind function using lseek()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quote from a reference:

> A call to rewind is equivalent to:
>
> fseek ( stream , 0L , SEEK_SET );
>
> except that, unlike fseek, rewind clears the error indicator.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/rewind/

Comment: I believe the cplusplus.com site has a few errors when interpreting the information for C. I prefer to consult the [POSIX site](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) for information.

Comment: In this case I believe it's right, and `rewind` is equivalent to that `fseek` call along with `clearerr` (with the lock held for the duration of both, on POSIX systems where locking is required).

Comment: It's also worth noting that you **can** achieve the equivalent of `rewind` with `clearerr` and `lseek` on the underlying file descriptor, as long as it's valid for the file descriptor to become the "active handle" at that point. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05_01 for details.